# LCSC parts for Coil & Capacitor

Tags: pcb-design, schematics

Greeting,

I'm using [This](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/561459a2e4b0b39f5cefa12e/t/5acac58cf950b7425218c2ea/1523238286703/bt840-32-evm-v4.pdf) Schematic as a reference to create a customized BLE PCB board.
I need some help to identify the below parts (with LCSC part No. if possible) as this is my first time to see those schematic symbols:-

- L1 and L2 120 Ohm Coils (may be current a coil for filtering)
- C5 and C6 Capacitors  (I guess it is a Polaroid capacitors where the +ve is the solid dot)
  [image]

PS: The real component are showing in the following picture
[image]

Comment: It is very strange to see a coil value given in "ohms".  Inductance comes in units of Henrys.  Either the board designer was confused (possibly using a ferrite bead that is 120\$\Omega\$ at some design frequency) or there is a mistranslation, or something.

Comment: Indeed, ferrite bead impedances are usually given as ohms at 100MHz frequency.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty of screenshotting the relevant parts of your schematic.

L1 and L2, which use this symbol:

[image]

are, I believe, ferrite beads, for filtering. The double bar represents a magnetic core; here, a solid bar is used, which is supposed to indicate the use of electrical steel (a dashed bar indicates ferrite) but many people who draw schematics don't reliably distinguish between these; it's likely this is a ferrite bead.

The capacitor symbols you mention, which appear like so:

[image]

I can only interpret as polarized capacitors. However, looking at your image of the board, they are populated with what looks like MLCCs, a non-polar type of capacitor. This indicates to me that the schematic is a few years older than the board, as 10μF used to be a lot to ask of a ceramic capacitor and designers would be more likely to use aluminum or tantalum electrolytics. Today, 10μF MLCCs are common enough that they've replaced electrolytics in many applications.

Note: I am not claiming to be an authoritative source on this. Take what I say with a grain of salt; this is just an engineer talking from experience reading schematics that sometimes include unusual symbols.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments @Hearth